# How to get H2o deeplearning Multinomial Model accuracy?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, h2o, auc

When I go for dl_model.show(), it shows me all the information but not the accuracy of the model and as well on the performance of Validation data it also not show the AUC. when I was running this command, I am getting this error

```
print('AUC', dl_model.auc(valid = False))


   KeyError                    Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-655-a4a2f0946c88> in <module>()
----> 1 print('AUC', dl_model.auc())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h2o\model\model_base.py in auc(self, train, valid, xval)
    682         tm = ModelBase._get_metrics(self, train, valid, xval)
    683         m = {}
--> 684         for k, v in viewitems(tm): m[k] = None if v is None else v.auc()
    685         return list(m.values())[0] if len(m) == 1 else m
    686 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h2o\model\metrics_base.py in auc(self)
    165     def auc(self):
    166         """The AUC for this set of metrics."""
--> 167         return self._metric_json['AUC']
    168 
    169     def pr_auc(self):

KeyError: 'auc'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you are not seeing the AUC metric it is because the H2O-Algo did not solve a binary classification problem.

If you want the accuracy for a multinomial problem use `[max_hit_ratio_k][1]` and look at `k=1`.

If you want to see metrics for multinomial in general, checkout what is available in the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html#module-h2o.model.multinomial), for example a confusion matrix and `mean_per_class_error` are both available.

Please find an example below: where the goal is to get the hit_ratio k = 1 (see last few lines)

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
h2o.init()

# import the iris dataset:
# this dataset is used to classify the type of iris plant
# the original dataset can be found at https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris
iris = h2o.import_file("http://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv")

# convert response column to a factor
iris['class'] = iris['class'].asfactor()

# set the predictor names and the response column name
predictors = iris.columns[:-1]
response = 'class'

# split into train and validation sets
train, valid = iris.split_frame(ratios = [.8])

# try using the `link` parameter:
# Initialize and train a GLM
iris_glm = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family = 'multinomial', link = 'family_default')
iris_glm.train(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train, validation_frame = valid)

pd = iris_glm.hit_ratio_table().as_data_frame()
pd.loc[(0,'hit_ratio')]
```

Comment: dl_model.max_hit_ratio_k[1] I tried this way but it shows this error                    
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: hi @SanjayKumar,  I added an explicit example for you - it would be great if you could mark the reply as accepted -, currently h2o-3 returns a twodimtable (specific to H2O) and requires specific slicing techniques if you are not comfortable with that you can just convert it to a pandas dataframe (which I showed) and get the hit ratio that way.

Comment: Hi @Lauren thanks for the example. I am getting the hit ratio table but not getting the reply of max_hit_ratio_k command.  And, k=1  on train data, I  get this value   0.5385539 and on test data this 0.1001860. Is it good or bad?

Comment: unfortunately there is a bug for the max_hit_ratio_k parameter...it doesn't do anything at the moment, sorry about that (https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5935).